# How to add values to href in which some value are from AJAX and some from PHP loop

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This above code is showing data of the selected ward.

```
$("#sel_ward").change(function () {
    var wardid = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'getWard-details.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {ward: wardid},
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function (response) {
            var len = response.length;
            // $("#sel_ward").empty();
            if (len == 0) {
                $("#sel_ward").append('<option value="">No Data Found</option>');
                var block_selected = response[i]['block_selected'];
                $("#blockid").val(block_selected);
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    var id = response[i]['id'];
                    var name = response[i]['name'];

                    var ward_parshad_name = response[i]['ward_parshad_name'];
                    var ward_parshad_contact = response[i]['ward_parshad_contact'];
                    var ward_population = response[i]['ward_population'];
                    var ward_house_count = response[i]['ward_house_count'];
                    var ward_voters_count = response[i]['ward_voters_count'];
                    var ward_polling_both_count = response[i]['ward_polling_both_count'];

                    var block_selected = response[i]['block_selected'];
                    var zone_selected = response[i]['zone_selected'];
                    var sector_selected = response[i]['sector_selected'];
                    var block_area = response[i]['block_area'];
                    var block_region = response[i]['block_region'];

                    $("#ward-name-view").text(name);
                    $("#ward-parshad-name-view").text(ward_parshad_name);
                    $("#ward-parshad-contact-view").text(ward_parshad_contact);
                    $("#ward-population-view").text(ward_population);
                    $("#ward-house-view").text(ward_house_count);
                    $("#ward-voters-view").text(ward_voters_count);
                    $("#ward-polling-booth-view").text(ward_polling_both_count);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Now i have list of committee whose data m getting through PHP

```
<?php
// Fetch Committee
$sql_block = "SELECT * FROM committee";
$block_data = mysqli_query($con, $sql_block);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($block_data)) {
    $committeeid = $row['sno'];
    $committee_name = $row['committee_name'];
    ?>
    <a id=committee href=""><span><?= $committee_name ?></span></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Now what i want is as soon as 1 of the committee is selected.. i want to take data from ward details as well as the committee id and name to the next page.
[THis will provide much clear view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh1uV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type=hidden id=committee_id value=<?=$committeeid?>>
<input type=hidden id=committee_name value=<?=$committee_name?>>


    var committeeid = $("#committee_id").val();
 $("#committee").click(function(){
window.open("index.php?id="+committeeid+"", '_blank');
 });
```

I used input tag to store the value and marked it as hidden. Then on click of committee item i fetched data from input and use it accordingly.